# How do i add a model with unique fields per entry, in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to setup an application that has a Hero model
and an Ability model, each hero has many Abilities.

Each Ability entry has some common fields, such as name, description, damage, range, duration. And so on.

But each entry should be able to have fields that are unique to that entry alone
for example, one single ability will have the fields: tether_duration and break_distance

How would i setup my models to be able to allow for this? Because i can't get my head around it right now

Answer (score 0):

You can always break it down by naming it and drawing it out.

Hero has many abilities 
Abilities has many heros
Abilities_attributes belongs to abilities. or maybe has many abilities.

If you break everything down into words it will help you model. Figure out what columns you want for each model. If you need to break those columns down even further you will need another model, if necessary.

As for your case.

It seems like you will need to create another model if your ability has sub categories.

hope it helps